# SQL Query JOIN on the same table for a given data

Tags: sql, oracle, join, h2

I have the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
  ID NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
  COMMON_SEQ NUMBER(22),
  NAME VARCHAR(20),
  CONSTRAINT PK_CONST PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, COMMON_SEQ, NAME) VALUES (1001, NULL, 'Michelle');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, COMMON_SEQ, NAME) VALUES (1002, NULL, 'Tiberius');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, COMMON_SEQ, NAME) VALUES (1003, NULL, 'Marigold');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, COMMON_SEQ, NAME) VALUES (1004, 999, 'Richmond');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, COMMON_SEQ, NAME) VALUES (1005, 999, 'Marianne');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, COMMON_SEQ, NAME) VALUES (1006, NULL, 'Valentin');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, COMMON_SEQ, NAME) VALUES (1007, 888, 'Juliette');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, COMMON_SEQ, NAME) VALUES (1008, NULL, 'Lawrence');
```

Some records in this table are related to each other by the common value of COMMON_SEQ (for example COMMON_SEQ of 999 relates Richmond and Marianne).

How can I select all names based on given ID as an input?

I tried joining table to itself (works ok when COMMON_SEQ is null). This example returns Michelle record:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.COMMON_SEQ,T.NAME
FROM TEST_TABLE T 
LEFT JOIN TEST_TABLE T2 ON NOT T.COMMON_SEQ is NULL 
  AND T.COMMON_SEQ=T2.COMMON_SEQ AND T.ID<>T2.ID
WHERE T.ID=1001
```

But it doesn't bring back 2 records for ID 1004. This example returns only Richmond record (but I need to return also Marianne record):

```
SELECT T.ID, T.COMMON_SEQ,T.NAME
FROM TEST_TABLE T 
LEFT JOIN TEST_TABLE T2 ON NOT T.COMMON_SEQ is NULL 
  AND T.COMMON_SEQ=T2.COMMON_SEQ AND T.ID<>T2.ID
WHERE T.ID=1004
```

How can I improve/rewrite the query to return Richmond and Marianne records when I supply only one ID value (either 1004 or 1005)?

Comment: Because `NULL = NULL` is not true. (you could use `x IS NOT DISTINCT FROM y`, if available )

Comment: Which database are you using? Oracle?

Comment: @Ramesh I use 2 databases: H2 and Oracle. I need common SQL that works for both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE t
WHERE COMMON_SEQ IN (SELECT COMMON_SEQ
                     FROM TEST_TABLE t1
                     WHERE t1.ID = 1004)
  OR t.ID = 1004;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ec7943f4a9829993b9979c107b2ab91)**

Passing the same parameter twice to handle `NULL` in `COMMON_SEQ`.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried and it returns expected results for all my test cases!

Comment: @user1697575 Great to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 SELECT COALESCE (ty.id, tx.id) AS id,
        COALESCE (ty.common_seq, tx.common_seq) AS common_seq,
        COALESCE (ty.name, tx.name) AS name
  FROM test_table tx LEFT OUTER JOIN test_table ty
             ON (tx.common_seq = ty.common_seq)
 WHERE tx.ID = 1004;
```

With this you can avoid using IN or EXISTS and this is likely to be more performant.

Comment: @user1697575 -  glad to help

Comment: just curious why did you use COALESCE function? Can't I just use  SELECT ty.* FROM ... ?

Comment: Why is a left join "likely to be more performant" than a semi-join (an IN  or EXISTS condition)? The reason I ask is that at least in Oracle, the opposite is true (and for obvious reasons: a semi-join has less work to do than a join).

Comment: @user1697575 - ty.* will only work for IDs which have a common_seq. You will get get NULL record if you tried id = 1001 for example.